# Why can't i able to access the Current.Application property under Async Call?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await, global-asax

I have a button to download some data from the database. I am trying to make this button call event a asynchronous one.

Under button click event i am calling the async method

```
       Public Delegate Function delAsyncMethodCaller()

       **ButtonClick Method**
        Dim obj As New delAsyncMethodCaller(AddressOf downloadReport)
        Dim iAr As IAsyncResult = obj.BeginInvoke(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AsyncComplete), Nothing)

       Public Function downloadReport()
       Dim objMargin As New clsOMACommon ---Getting Null Reference Exception
        ------Some Operation--------
       End Function

       Public Class clsOMACommon
       Public strConn As String = Current.Application("ConnectionString").ToString.Trim --->The Current.Application is Nothing.
       Public strDBOwner As String = Zurrent.Application("strDBOwner").ToString.Trim
       ------Some Operation------------
       End Class
```

So when i am calling the async method, inside which i am initializing an object where i am getting an null reference exception because of Current.Application is Nothing.

How can i fix this?